# Within the context of a document term matrix, what exactly are x and y axis in kmeans clustering?

Tags: r, k-means

I'm reading up on kmeans and following a blog post to do some text analysis.

I watched a [helpful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ao2vnhelKhI) by Andrew Ng fro Coursera which really helped my understanding of what is going on. Here is a screen shot from the video:

[image: kmeans clustering]

So far kmeans makes sense, start with K cluster centroids, assign each point to a cluster based on distance (Euclidean?), recalculate mean, repeat.

But I'm also following [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html) blog post on text analysis in R. Following the article I make a document term matrix.

Context is online survey results. Let's say there are e.g. 10k survey results and a total of 15k "tokens", so a dtm of 10k*15k.

Further down the article we are shown an example of kmeans clustering on the dtm:

```
library(fpc)   
d <- dist(t(dtmss), method="euclidian")   
kfit <- kmeans(d, 2)   
clusplot(as.matrix(d), kfit$cluster, color=T, shade=T, labels=2, lines=0)
```

And it works.

But I'm trying to understand how. An example in kmeans clustering I found online was weight and height on the x,y axis for determining how to split a population for clothing sizes of small, medium and large. That makes sense.

But in the context of a DTM, what would be on the x and y axis in the screen shot above? It's just not clicking.

Comment: kmeans should be run **on the data matrix, not on the distance matrix**! I don't think that is a very good blog post.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I'm copying from here: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html

Comment: Blog posts sometimes hack together something without understanding what is does, unfortunately. In particular, this approach increases the complexity form O(n) to O(n^2) both in time and memory.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse OK... thanks for the feedback. So hold my hand here. I should change kfit <- kmeans(d, 2) to what exactly?

Comment: when you say "on the data matrix" you mean the dtm yes?

Comment: Yes. I'm surprised to see it transposed there - maybe that blog example also built it transposed instead of the usual way.

Comment: If it is transposed then technically it is a term-document matrix. And I agree with Anony-Mousse that they should have used k-medoids instead of k-means in that article, but that is a discussion for CV, not SO.

Comment: @BryanGoggin well, spherical k-means is a fairly standard technique. But it operates on the document-term matrix, not on a distance matrix (and is equivalent to k-means on a normalized document-term matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article did not cluster on the DTM, but on the distance matrix as returned by `dist.` The function `dist` computes the euclidean distance between vectors, and `kmeans` uses this measure to cluster on. Think of each document as an observation and each unique term you have as a dimension. `kmeans` is comparing the distance between the high-dimensional vectors that represent the columns of the DTM and clustering vectors that are similar with one another based on the distance metric.

To visualize what `dist` does, imagine a 3 dimensional box. `dist` could be used to measure the straight-line distance from, say, the front, bottom, left corner to the back, top, right corner (see image).

[image]

Even if the box is a perfect cube, this distance is not equal to the length of one of the sides, the same way that the diagonal of a square (green line of the bottom) is not the same length as the sides of the square. Now imagine going up into 4, 5, ... , N dimensions. The euclidean distance formula (given in the image for 2 and 3 dimensions) can be extended to give the distance between two vectors in any number of dimensions.

For an example using words, think of "the quick brown fox" as a vector with values of 1 for "the", "quick", "brown", and fox". "The lazy dog" is another vector with values of 1 for "the", "lazy", and "dog", but 0's for "quick", "brown" and "fox".

```
         the quick brown fox lazy dog
words.1   1     1     1   1    0   0
words.2   1     0     0   0    1   1

dist(words)

         words.1
words.2 2.236068
```

`dist` gives the length of the line that would connect the vectors `words.1` and `words.2` in this 6 dimensional space. If we had multiple vectors in this space, `dist` would return a matrix (technically my example returned a 1 x 1 matrix) of the distance between each vector and every other vector in the space, similar to what a covariance matrix does. Vectors that are more similar can be thought of as "closer together" than vectors that are different. We can go back to the cube example, but still with words, now:

```
     front back top bottom left right
V1     1    0   0      1    1     0
V2     0    1   1      0    0     1
V3     1    0   0      1    0     1
```

Just like in the picture above, the front, bottom, left vector (V1) is as far away (or as different) as possible than the back, top, right vector (V2). We expect that V1 and V2 will be the furthest from each other, and since V1 and V3 have 2 words ("front" and "bottom") in common, we expect the V1 to V3 distance to be less.

```
dist(a)
      V1       V2
V2 2.449490         
V3 1.414214 2.000000
```

We were correct. The V1 to V2 distance is 2.44, which is greater than the V1 to V3 distance (1.141) and V2 distance to V3 distance (2).

This matrix of distances is what `kmeans` is using to cluster.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. "The function dist computed the euclidean distance between vectors". At the point d is created d <- dist(t(dtmss), method="euclidian"), what is the vector(s) at this point in time? I looked at head(d) str(d) and it's a class object. The first value in there on my actual data is 68.19091 and the label is "someword". What does that mean? What is 68.19091 in this context? My cognitive abilities are just not sharp enough

Comment: I edited my answer. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. A small follow up, if you will. In the first matrix you showed distance between V1 and V2 dist(words) as 2.23.
Looking at the distance formula at the top of the answer, how did that come to be? I tried √4 ( which is 2) minus √3 (which is 1.73) = 0.27. √4 and 3 because the formula √x1 +xn. How would one calculate the 2.23 distance? Again, really grateful for your time in explaining this so far

Comment: In the first example (the quick brown fox, etc) there are 6 possible dimensions. However, for the dimension "the" both vectors have the value of 1. So the formula would be the square root of (1-1)^2 ("the") + (1-0)^2 ("quick")+ ... +(0-1)^2 ("dog") which is `sqrt(0+1+1+1+1+1) = sqrt(5) = 2.236068`.

Comment: Can't underline enough how helpful this has been. I get it now - thank you so much. You're last comment above really nails where I was getting confused

Comment: kneans *should* be run **on the data matrix**. Running it on the distance matrix has a different semantic, does not yield meaningful centers, and is O(n^2), i.e. much more expensive and will not scale.

Comment: Thanks for down-voting my answer for a completely off topic reason. I was answering Doug's question, as asked, about the article's code and the use of `dist` function. If you have a problem with **how the article uses k-means** then take that up with them.

Comment: It will mistakenly lead people to believe that k-means works on distance matrixes. It should be made clear that k-means expects to see the raw data, not a distance matrix. Otherwise you don't get e.g. a centroid.

Comment: Are both the x axis and y axis euclidian distances between the words in the document. How can there be negative values?

Comment: strictly positive values